# create table user("user_id int auto_increment"); not working in derby (embedded database)

Tags: java, mysql, derby

I am new in derby library. why I got this error when I use the auto_increment in my query?

here is my java code

```
 this.conn.createStatement().execute(create table user("user_id int auto_increment, PRIMARY KEY(user_id))");
```

I tried this in mysql server and its works but in derby I got this error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "auto_increment" at line 1
```

why I got this error?

Comment: AFAIK there is no `auto_increment` in Derby, look for [IDENTITY](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop132.html) columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derby does not have auto_increment as a keyword. In derby you need to use identity columns to implement auto increment behaviour

For example

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
name VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(1024),
CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;
```

Above statement will create Student table with id as auto increment column and primary key as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad that helped you :)